# How can I initialize sample variable in Jmeter?

Tags: csv, jdbc, jmeter, response

I have scenario as :

While Controller

```
CSV Data Config
  Switch Controller
    Register_Scenario
       HTTP Request
          HTTP Header Manager
          Regular Expression Extractor
       JDBC Request
          Response Assertion
    Cancel_Scenario
       HTTP Request
          HTTP Header Manager
          Regular Expression Extractor
       JDBC Request
          Response Assertion
```

View Result Tree

In my CSV I have multiple scenarios to Register and Cancel with different data
Eg:

```
Scenario,Subject,StudentID

Register_Scenario,ABC,1

Cancel_Scenario,XYZ,5

Register_Scenario,MATH,200
```

I am running Web API and getting the output from Database in one variable(its in Json format in Database), I would like to store that response data coming from JDBC request into the CSV file:

My expected OUTPUT should be:

[image: expected output]

Now, I used sample variable in JDBC request in the "Variable names"=Json_Response

I ran the scenario using data mentioned above

I am getting this as output:

[image: Actual output]

I believe my result is generating twice as in one scenario I have HTTP request and JDBC request, However variable is defined only on JDBC request and not HTTP request. and for it stays same until value changes..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the `null` value when your `Register_Scenario` variable has not been initialized yet you can explicitly set its value to whatever you want (empty or something else) using [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) configuration element

[image: JMeter User Defined Variables]

Comment: Actually I tried using User Defined variable and tried to reinitialize but it doesn't re-initialise. the it picks up the value from the previous result. Json_response is my sample variable for JDBC request and not for HTTP request. Eg. So when my first scenario wll run, Register_scenario it will run HTTP request here Json_response is null , then it will run JDBC reques, in this Json_response will get populated. after that next scenario will run Cancel_scenario in this for HTTP request Json_response is from previous request which is wrong.